# Django-CSP - AJAX request with vanilla JS blocked by CSP

Tags: javascript, django, post, content-security-policy

I have a Django-based D&D-wiki webpage that I'm working on in my free time which I'm using to learn more about web development.
I recently implemented a Content-Security-Policy using [django-csp.](https://django-csp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) That went well and the switch was fairly painless, given that I only had 20 or so templates to deal with. Here my CSP settings:

```
//Django settings.py
CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'none'",)
CSP_STYLE_SRC = ("'self'", 'stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com', 'fonts.googleapis.com', "'unsafe-inline'", 'cdn.jsdelivr.net', 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com', 'rawcdn.githack.com', 'maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com',)
CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = ("'self'", 'localhost', "default-src", 'stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com', 'code.jquery.com', 'cdn.jsdelivr.net', 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com','maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com',)
CSP_IMG_SRC = ("'self'", 'ipw3.org', 'data:', 'cdn.jsdelivr.net', 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com', 'i.imgur.com',)
CSP_FONT_SRC = ("'self'", 'fonts.gstatic.com', 'maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com',)
CSP_MEDIA_SRC = ("'self'",)
CSP_INCLUDE_NONCE_IN = ('style-src',)
```

Even more recently started learning about AJAX requests and wanted to implement a simple POST request.
Sadly, my CSP blocks this request, which I believe should be allowed given that I allowed self and localhost in CSP_SCRIPT_SRC:

```
//JS Event Listener that creates and sends the AJAX request
    document.getElementById('create-timstamp').addEventListener('click', function(event){ 
        const isValid = validateForm();
        if (isValid){
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', getCreateTimestampURL(), true);            
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
            const csrf = document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value;
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", csrf);

            xhr.onload = function(){
                document.querySelector('.timestamp-create-box').remove();
            }

            const timestampForm = document.forms['timestamp-form'];
            const timestamp_seconds = toTimeInt(timestampForm['time'].value);
            const timestamp_name = timestampForm['name'].value;
            const data = `name=${timestamp_name}&time=${timestamp_seconds}`;

            xhr.send(data);
            
            return false;
        }


//For completion's sake here also the helper methods used by the event listener
function getCreateTimestampURL(){
    return document.querySelector('#add-timestamp').dataset.timestampcreateurl;
}

function toTimeInt(timestampString){
    const hours = parseInt(timestampString.substring(0,2));
    const minutes = parseInt(timestampString.substring(3,5));
    const seconds = parseInt(timestampString.substring(6,8));
    return 3600*hours + 60*minutes + seconds;
}
```

And here the browser's response:

```
//Webbrowser console output after triggering the event
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:8002/files/timestamp/1/17/new (“default-src”).
```

So I know I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. I know I need to adjust my CSP settings somehow, but I'm already allowing localhost-scripts, what else is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through [the django-csp documentation](https://django-csp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#policy-settings) one more time I finally found the entry I was looking for. Not sure how I missed it the first few times.

The entry you want to change is `CSP_CONNECT_SRC`, which naturally needs to allow `("'self'",)` to be able to send AJAX requests.

That does **not** mean that the above code for a request would work. The way it grabs a CSRF Token is non-functional and leads to errors. This just gets past the CSP blockage.